# Does Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 support DotNetCore 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have recently migrate DotNetCore 1.1 to DotNetCore 2.2. It seems 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 only support DotNetCore 2.1. I am getting the following error:

> This version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All is only compatible with the
>   netcoreapp2.1 target framework. Please target netcoreapp2.1 or choose
>   a version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All compatible with
>   netcoreapp2.2.    QNPROJECTS.CORE.API .nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.all\2.1.4\build\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All.targets

Comment: I think its in preview... check this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Comment: The simple answer (as stated in your error) is no, it doesn't. You'll need ASP.NET Core 2.2 or higher to work with .NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Kirk Larkin in the comments, ASP.NET Core 2.2 or higher is needed to work with .NET Core 2.2.

You can check which target frameworks are supported by a nuget package by checking to see if the desired framework is listed as a dependency [here](https://www.nuget.org/).

An option that I find more reliable (as sometimes the nuget.org website doesn't list the dependencies for some packages) is to use the [nuget package explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) which can be used by searching a package up, selecting the correct version, and opening the lib folder to see if  the desired framework is supported.